# jsonファイルをdesirializeする際、値の記載がない場合の検知について

Tags: c#, json

配列が定義されたjsonから読み込んだ値を使用するプログラムを作成しています。

- 値はjsonファイルに記載された値を使用する。
- jsonファイルにプロパティ未記載の場合は配列の直前の要素の値を使用する。

以下のクラスでjsonファイル例をdeserializeすると未記載の場合は0となるため値として0を記載された場合に判定できず困っています。

```
using System.text.Json;
internal class Value
{
    public int Front { get; set; }
    public int Back { get; set; }
}
```

jsonファイル例

```
[
  {
    "Front": 2000,
    "Back": 2000,
  },
  {
    "Back": 3000,
  },
  {
    "Front": 0,
  }
]
```

Comment: > (2)jsonファイルにプロパティ未記載の場合は前回記載された値を使用する。 <= これの「前回」とは何ですか？

Comment: デシリアライザは何を使ってますか？

Comment: 「前回記載された値」の定義も明確に説明してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
>デシリアライザは何を使ってますか？ – 
System.text.Jsonを使用しています。

> (2)jsonファイルにプロパティ未記載の場合は前回記載された値を使用する。 <= これの「前回」とは何ですか


わかりにくくすいません。例で書かせてもらったjsonファイルでいいますと、”Front":2000 と"Back":2000を読み込んだ後、次の"Back":3000を読み込んだ際、Frontは2000の値を使用する事を
”前回記載された値を使用する"と記載しました。

Answer (score 3):

JSONのパーサーに何を使っているかにもよるのですが、一般的には[null許容値型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)を使用するとnullかどうかで判定できることが多いです。
具体的には以下のように変更してみてください。

```
internal class Value
{
  public int? Front { get; set; }
  public int? Back { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

使っているデシリアライザが何だか不明ですが、System.Text.Json または Newtonsoft.Json を使うとして、

> jsonファイルにプロパティ未記載の場合は前回記載された値を使用する

の「前回記載された値」というのが何だか不明ですが配列の直前の要素の値を使うとして、さらに Value クラスの定義は変更しないという条件で、以下のようにしてできると思います。.NET 6.0 のコンソールアプリです。

```
#nullable disable
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string json = @"[
  {
    ""Front"": 2000,
    ""Back"": 2000,
  },
  {
    ""Back"": 3000,
  },
  {
    ""Front"": 0,
  },
  {
    ""Front"": 555,
    ""Back"": 666,
  },
  {
  }
]";

// System.Text.Json
JsonElement jsonElement = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(json,
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        AllowTrailingCommas = true
    });
List<Value> list1 = new List<Value>();
if (jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
{
    int prevFront = -1;
    int prevBack = -1;
    bool isFrontSet, isBackSet;
    foreach (JsonElement jelemInArray in jsonElement.EnumerateArray())
    {
        if (jelemInArray.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
        {
            var value = new Value();
            isFrontSet = false;
            isBackSet = false;
            foreach (JsonProperty jprop in jelemInArray.EnumerateObject())
            {
                if (jprop.Name == "Front")
                {
                    value.Front = prevFront = jprop.Value.GetInt32();
                    isFrontSet = true;
                }
                if (jprop.Name  == "Back")
                {
                    value.Back = prevBack = jprop.Value.GetInt32();
                    isBackSet = true;
                }                
            }

            if (isFrontSet == false)
            {
                value.Front = prevFront;
                isFrontSet = true;
            }
            if (isBackSet == false)
            {
                value.Back = prevBack;
                isBackSet = true;
            }

            list1.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

// Newtonsoft.Json
JToken jtoken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
List<Value> list2 = new List<Value>();
if (jtoken is JArray)
{
    int prevFront = -1;
    int prevBack = -1;
    bool isFrontSet, isBackSet;
    foreach (JToken jtokenInArray in (JArray)jtoken)
    {
        if (jtokenInArray is JObject)
        {
            var value = new Value();
            isFrontSet = false;
            isBackSet = false;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> kvp in (JObject)jtokenInArray)
            {
                if (kvp.Key == "Front")
                {
                    value.Front = prevFront = (int)kvp.Value;
                    isFrontSet = true;
                }
                if (kvp.Key == "Back")
                {
                    value.Back = prevBack = (int)kvp.Value;
                    isBackSet = true;
                }
            }

            if (isFrontSet == false)
            {
                value.Front = prevFront;
                isFrontSet = true;
            }
            if (isBackSet == false)
            {
                value.Back = prevBack;
                isBackSet = true;
            }

            list2.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

public class Value
{
    public int Front { get; set; }
    public int Back { get; set; }
}
```

結果は以下のようになります（Visual Studio のデバッグ画像）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: System.Text.Json を使用しています。サンプルコードまでありがとございます。試してみます。

Comment: 上に書いたように「Value クラスの定義は変更しないという条件」なのですが、Bladean Mericle さんの回答で書かれたようにプロパティの型を int? 型に変更できるならそう変更して、List<Value> にデシリアライズするのがお勧めです。「配列の直前の要素の値を使用する」ということろは null となっているところを探して書き換えれば済むでしょうから、その方が簡単かつ確実だと思います。